# Storyboard not linking to @IBAction/Outlet in ViewController.swift Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, iboutlet, ibaction, xcode-storyboard

I'm trying to link an element in an Xcode Storyboard to an `@IBAction` or `@IBOutlet` but when I drag-and-drop in the assistant editor I cannot place the connection. The blue line does not settle, just hovers. Even if I try to manually connect (by typing `@IBAction func test(_ sender: Any){}` the little circle to the left does not settle. I've tried to use `(_ sender: NSButton) {}` but even that does not work. 
This is making me lose time, and not being able to reference an NSButton out of storyboards is just not helpful!! 
I don't know if this is an Xcode 9 bug, yet most others don't have this issue. I’ve looked at other SO questions but they are mostly for iOS/UIKit, not for Cocoa Frameworks and the answers haven't worked for me anyway.
I'm developing in Xcode 9, Swift 4 and for Mac
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you set class name to the vc you want to drag the elements to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you didn't set the `ViewController` class in the storyboard.

1. Select story board
2. Select the Viewcontroller
3. Select Identity inspector

[image]

4. Enter your ViewController classe's name
5. Now try and link it again.

Comment: Thanks @JayMayu it worked!! My only question is whether changing the custom class affects it's behaviour? (Aside from allowing me to connect via `IBOutlet` or `IBAction`)

Comment: Yes, it changes everything. You are mapping a class to the view controller in the storyboard. If you remove it abruptly, then the mappings are gone and the app will start to crash. If you want to change the class always remove all reference to the IBOutlets and IBActions.